# Date being stored as null

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I have an oracle 11g DB and a table with the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE
VW_BLACKLIST
(
    MSISDN VARCHAR2(15),
    OFFERCODE1 VARCHAR2(192),
    EVENT_TYPE VARCHAR2(64),
    INSERT_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FINAL_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+30,
    APPLICATIONNAME VARCHAR2(15),
    AGENT_ID VARCHAR2(20),
    SESSION_ID VARCHAR2(50),
    PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR2(64),
    UACIOFFERTRACKINGCODE VARCHAR2(1536)
);
```

Using this statement to insert data:

```
INSERT into TEIRSYS.VW_BLACKLIST(MSISDN,OFFERCODE1,EVENT_TYPE,INSERT_DATE,FINAL_DATE,APPLICA‌​TIONNAME,AGENT_ID,SESSION_ID,PRODUCT_ID,UACIOFFERTRACKINGCODE) 
values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

I ran a test application that was trying to input the following date 'Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 AST 2015' into the column INSERT_DATE and FINAL_DATE. The DDL has default current timestamp, so why am I still getting null in INSERT_DATE?

Comment: Show us how your insert statement looks like.

Comment: Hi Evaldas, I have the following insert statement being executed in the logs: INSERT into TEIRSYS.VW_BLACKLIST(MSISDN,OFFERCODE1,EVENT_TYPE,INSERT_DATE,FINAL_DATE,APPLICATIONNAME,AGENT_ID,SESSION_ID,PRODUCT_ID,UACIOFFERTRACKINGCODE) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
and the actual values aren't shown in the logs. But the input parameters are listed and they dont contain any values for insert_date which is why I am confused why the null is being inserted.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. **Edit** your question. The `insert` statement alone is not enough, show us the code that runs that provides the parameter for the statement and runs it.

Answer (score 0):

Your input format is wrong. Did you try other formats?

```
yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mi:ssam
```

Is a good format.

You could also refer to [this](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that's what I had first thought but then FINAL_DATE is being populated with the same kind of input parameter which is why I got confused.

Comment: What do you mean with `same kind of input parameter`? Add some more details if this didn't help you.

Comment: I meant the same date was input into FINAL_DATE and it was logged in the database.

Comment: I think you have to debug whatever program/script you wrote. Somewhere you crossed Final_Date with Insert_Date